# C incompatible Types struct return

Tags: c, struct

The following code gives me a Compile error "incompatible types at assignment"

File 1:

```
struct a{
  int b;
}
```

File 2:

```
static struct a c;

void test(){
   c.b = 0;
}

struct a getStruct(){
   test();
   return c;
}
```

File 3:

```
static struct a d;

void setStruct(){
   d = getStruct(); (<-- Error)
}
```

I've searched for this and can't find my mistake.

Comment: Compiler usually provide information where the error occurs. Could you provide whole error statement?

Comment: I suppose files 2 and 3 also include file 1? Do show the complete files.

Comment: My guess is that the compiler isn't shown when compiling file 3 what the type of `getStruct` is, so it assumes `int`.

Comment: yes 2 and 3 include file 1

Comment: i change struct d in FIle 3 with a int and now it works, so that what you say is right or? But how can i fix it?

Comment: Probably file 3 doesn't see either the struct definition or `getStruct`. It's a pretty dysfunctional program design to have `getStruct` in one file and `setStruct` in another.

Comment: yeah i know, but i cant change that.

Comment: Ok it works, i only integrate a prototype from that function. Ty guys!!

Comment: Please always turn up your warning level. The compiler should complain about using a function without previous declaration. That should directly point you to missing prototype.

Comment: The root of the problem might be that you compile as C90. You should use a better compiler or configure the one you are using correctly. For older versions of gcc (older than 5.0.0) you have to compile with `-std=c99` or it goes dinosaur mode on you.